# The String cor passed from main activity to selector acitvity. Date is displayed but the string is not displayed

Tags: android

Passing date from date picker and string from edit text through intent from main activity to selector activity
**mainactivity**

```
 et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cour);
final String cor = et2.getText().toString();
  day=dp.getDayOfMonth();
                mon=dp.getMonth();
                year=dp.getYear();
                i.putExtra("courses",cor);
                i.putExtra("number", e);
                i.putExtra("day", day);i.putExtra("mon", mon);i.putExtra("year", year);

                i.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(i);
```

**selector activity**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        // String date;

 if(extras!=null) {
     result = extras.getInt("number");
     day = extras.getInt("day");

     mon = extras.getInt("mon");
     //mon =1;
     year = extras.getInt("year");
     cor = extras.getString("courses");
     act = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     act.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/" + months[mon] + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
     //String r = myDB2.retrive(cor);
     act.append(cor);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't append String to TextView, Append String to String.

```
     year = extras.getInt("year");
     cor = extras.getString("courses");
     act = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     String yourText = String.valueOf(day) + "/" + months[mon] + "/" + String.valueOf(year) + " " + cor;
     act.setText(yourText);
     //String r = myDB2.retrive(cor);
     //act.append(cor);
```

Comment: Tried doing this:  act.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/" + months[mon] + "/" + String.valueOf(year) + " "+cor); but did not help

Comment: Check the cor String, print the value? It may be empty string. Is that date is displaying after adding above line?

Comment: yes, the date is being displayed but not the string cor

Comment: Oh I think the cor text may be empty string check print like this
Log.d("Test cor", "Text is " + cor + "printing"); and check in your logcat

Comment: in logcat I got this: 01-05 11:16:51.383 20957-20957/com.example.sankar.kjsr7c D/Test cor: Text is printing

Comment: Oh ok then surely cor String is empty. Make sure you are correctly assigning the values to cor and passing through the intent.

Comment: @Kommurujaishankarreddy did you resolve this problem? Is this answer helps for you? Please make sure to accept the answer.